CLion fills editor with spaces

CLion fills end of rows with spaces, making it hard to navigate when clicking on the end of a row. Can't seem to find a setting for this. Does anyone know a fix for this?
I have looked in the settings and searched for this setting, but can't seem to find anyone with the same problem.

You'll probably get more help in the CLion Forum.

Found the solution: command+shift+8
